# "Command 'teqc' not found..." error occurs when trying to run teqc in ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, command

I'm hoping you can help me with my problem. I am trying to execute a program, teqc. It is located in /home/iraya/teqc. When i tried running it to the terminal, this error occurs

Command 'teqc' not found, did you mean:command 'texc' from deb doomsday (2.3.1+ds1-1build1)
Try: sudo apt install

I tried running teqc in its terminal and the same error occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the program you're trying to run but I'm assuming you might've missed some installation steps. Have you added the program's folder to your system's PATH?